# Wifi card not detected - Debian Linux

Tags: debian, drivers

I have been trying for two days to setup my wifi card with Debian 8 (AMD64) without success. I paste here what I have about my hardware configuration :

Computer : Lenovo Yoga 500

Wifi chipset : Broadcom bcm4352 or bcm43ae (I'm not sure of what I have to use).

```
    lshw -C network
  *-network NON-RÉCLAMÉ   
       description: Network controller
       produit: Broadcom Corporation
       fabriquant: Broadcom Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 02
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       ressources: mémoire:d4400000-d4407fff mémoire:d4000000-d43fffff
```

Another piece of information :

```
 lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 43ae (rev 02)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1347 (rev ff)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Lenovo, HP and Dell are bad actors who rebrand cards in orders to force you to upgrade from them. *If* they are not officially supported, either you fake the proper ID of them, or the drivers have to account for the new vendor IDs, or you can do it with udev. Often also the firmware has to be loaded with binary blobs, have you installed at least firmware-linux-free ?

Comment: I didn't know the situation of those actors. Yes, I tried with the firmware-linux-free package but it doesn't work. The wifi card is not detected. I also tried with the Linux driver from Broadcom [link](https://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11) but it's the same result.

Comment: http://goughlui.com/2014/08/02/laptop-wireless-card-whitelists-an-upgrade-nightmare/ "Users of other operating systems, for example, Linux may have to contend with the fact the adapter supplied may be poorly supported without any option to change to a better supported adapter."

Comment: Mmm... well, the situation speaks for itself. Indeed, it's not an easy way... I'm still searching for a solution. Maybe something to do with Ndiswrapper package

Comment: If I had bought it in FNAC and was still under the 30 days return policy I would return it. ;) https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20150812/11395231925/lenovo-busted-stealthily-installing-crapware-via-bios-fresh-windows-installs.shtml

Comment: Have you check this https://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx

Comment: To Rui F Rubeiro : I would do it also ;-) (after reading this article) Unfortunately the computer has expired the 30 days return policy... What a wonderful world isn't it ? So, I dig the topic ;)

To user137124 : Yes, I tried also but not working

Answer (score 0):

What about installing `broadcom-sta-dkms` with all it requirements?

> Broadcom STA is a binary-only device driver to support the following
>   IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n wireless network … and BCM4352-based hardware